# Should I separate my js files one for mobile screens and one for big screens? Or just one big file?

Tags: javascript, css

So, I have an eCommerce project and it's a middle-large project. And I'm making it responsive.

I have made 2 separate CSS files one for mobiles (very small) and one for PC and the PC will load both the styles (Mobile and PC).

Anyway, the question is should I take the same approach with my JS files? Or it's not needed in mobiles.

Comment: You need not. Again, you should use css-materials(angular-material, bootstrap) to make your more recognizable and responsive.

Comment: @Sourav actually I do need. Bootstrap and other CSS libraries/frameworks are going to die and it's actually so nice being able to do and achieve whatever I want. I used Bootstrap and it was great but it's no match to my styling greatness lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon the feature of your website. If your website doesn't use the JS files then its good to separate it from mobile device view points.

However, you can add `async` or `defer` to your js files. Here's what the `async` and `defer` attributes do:

Async Attribute: The `async` attribute loads the script asynchronously. In other words, ensures that the script loads asynchronously along side the other contents of the page, after which it is executed.

Defer Attribute: The `defer` attribute defers loading of the script. It ensures that the script is executed only after all contents of the page have finished loading.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it. I just needed to make sure!